# python argument instanceId, REGION, Key_TAG, Value

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

modified it and works but need to get the list from csv of multiple instance Ids

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3
import sys
import argparse
instance_id = sys.argv[1]
aws_region = sys.argv[2]
#TAG_KEY = sys.argv[3]
#VALUE = sys.argv[4]


EC2_RESOURCE = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=aws_region)

def tag_instance(instance_id):
    
    TAGS = [
    {
        'Key': 'Name',
        'Value': 'xxxxxx'
    }
    ]

    instances = EC2_RESOURCE.instances.filter(
    InstanceIds=[
        instance_id,
    ],
    )

    for instance in instances:
        instance.create_tags(Tags=TAGS)
    print(f'Tags successfully added to the instance {instance.id}')

tag_instance(instance_id)
```

I changed it around a bit. got it working but I need to put in multiple instance_id or read the list from csv file

Comment: What are you trying to read from csv, the key, value?

Comment: "InstanceId","REGION","Key_TAG","Value"

Comment: Have a look at `sys.argv` for accessing positional parameters that you pass to your script.   You will need to import the `sys` module.

Comment: Could you reformulate the question such that it is understandable? What would you want to do?

Comment: I want to tag multiple instances at one time. read from csv file or be able to enter all the instance Ids and tag them all at once